# geopandas shape files coordinates

Tags: geopandas, shapefile, coordinate-systems

I'm currently trying to create geojson files from a set of shape files.

```
for shape_file in shape_files[1:]:

    print(fileName(shape_file))

    shp = geopandas.read_file(shape_file)
    shp.to_crs(epsg = '4326')

    file_name = shape_file[0:len(shape_file) - len('.shp')] + '.geojson'

    print(file_name)
    print('Adding to JSON file')

    shp.to_file(file_name, driver = 'GeoJSON')

    print(fileName(file_name) + ' JSON file created.')

print()
print('DONE')
```

One of the problems is that the coordinates are not in the format I would like to use.

To combat this I've altered the code to edit the coordinate system but I'm now getting this error.

RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The dtype to put the epsg in is incorrect. If you declare epsg it must be int. So your code should look like this:

```
shp.to_crs(epsg = 4326)
```

or

```
shp.to_crs('epsg:4326')
```